# Why is my class not visible outside the file?

Tags: php, class, include, visibility

I have 2 PHP files as part of a website. The first one has the API functions (pre made ready to use requests), and the other one has the code itself that will call the functions from the first one.

The API file looks like:

```php
<?php
class API_REQUESTS {
    public static function GetSomeData() {
        return some_request('some_url');
    }
}
?>
```

And the other file — where I want to use the API functions — looks like:

```php
<?php
include '..\path\to\api\api.php';

echo API_REQUESTS.GetSomeData();
?>
```

I am using XAMPP and it should be setup correctly sense everything works fine except for the php file it self

However, when running the code, I get the following error:

```php
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "API_REQUESTS" in "path\to\index.php":3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in "path\to\index.php" on line 3
```

I thought that I might have made a mistake in the include path but when I tried to change it, it gives me a new `Warning: include 'wrong\path' Failed to open stream: No such file or directory`, so the path is right.

I also tried using `require` and `require_once` but I still encounter the `Fatal error`.

Comment: `API_REQUESTS.GetSomeData()` is not proper PHP syntax. You want `API_REQUESTS::GetSomeData()` for a static call. Also, you might want to read about [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and use an accepted convention like naming your class `ApiRequests` instead of `API_REQUESTS`.

Comment: yes Thank you, just discovered that and posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

its been a long time sense i used PHP so i forgot that in PHP i should use the
`::` operator instead of `.` to access a class's static members

so the code should look like this :

```
<?php
include '..\path\to\api\api.php';

echo API_REQUESTS::GetSomeData();
?>
```